# Wouldn't a black-hole starship quickly lose its black hole?

Tags: black-holes, propulsion

There seem to be somewhat serious proposals to propel a starship using a black hole (after all it has its own [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_starship) page!). The idea is to use the Hawking radiation from a small black hole and a reflector to direct the Hawking radiation out behind you. However wouldn't this just push the black hole away from the ship? I skimmed a paper on the topic a while ago, but I didn't find anything about how to 'attach' the black hole to the ship. This issue isn't mentioned in the 'criticisms' section of the Wikipedia article, but it seems like a hard problem.

Comment: You can edit the Wikipedia page yourself if you think you can improve it.

Comment: You can keep a black hole only by either electromagnetic or gravitational attraction to the ship.